# What could cause $_FILES['file']['name'] to be empty?

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

I have a form which includes a file upload. Everything in the form seems to be working fine except that the `$_FILES['file']['name']` turns up empty.

**HTML**

```
<form ... >
<input class="file" type="file" name="file[]" />
<input class="file" type="file" name="file[]" />
<input class="file" type="file" name="file[]" />
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $index => $file) {
    // Handle file upload
}
```

I get an error saying that the index `$_FILES['file']` is not defined. I've checked that file upload is enabled in PHP. What else could be causing this to turn up empty?

Comment: `var_dump` the `$_FILES` array, it might help you.

Comment: I have found that when doing an array of files is submitted in a different structure from an array of (lets say) hidden inputs.

Comment: @slugonamission: tried the var dump: it's a completely empty array...

Comment: post the whole form code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is the enctype right?

Try

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input class="file" type="file" name="file[]" />
   <input class="file" type="file" name="file[]" />
   <input class="file" type="file" name="file[]" />
</form>
```

Without **enctype** no files will be uploaded, so the `$_FILES` array will be empty.

Comment: Wow, good call! My enctype was `enctype="multipart/form-datad"` with a rogue `d` at the end - it was messing up the whole thing. Thanks!